Reasons for deleted questions and requesting to undelete questions
I had asked few questions . One of them is the following :
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/human-brother-sister-bonding
It was a fairly interesting topic to ponder about and I would love to extend this question to include even mother-son relationship, which was what I planned initially . I guess in that case the answer might bear some connections to oedipus complex theory and hence this complex is a bit distant to sibling bonding between people from opposite gender and as such I thought of putting that question exclusively for the latter. 
May I know what happened?

I believe it automatically got removed for the following reason.

If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...

has −1 or lower score
has no answers
is not locked


However, given that no comment was left behind by the one down voter I decided to undelete the question. I wrote an edit which hopefully improves on it slightly.
As always, try doing some initial research when writing a question. It helps in attracting up votes, so that a similar scenario won't happen in the future! Read the FAQ to learn how to phrase good questions, and look at other up voted questions to see examples of how to frame a good question.

The question was automatically deleted again, for the same reason...
